# Rxjs assign value in observable to global variable

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

Sorry new to angular and async programming, i am trying to assign value from rxjs observable to a global variable, something like this:

```
public currentUser: User;

this.userService.getAuthUser().subscribe(user => {
  this.currentUser = user;
});
console.log(this.currentUser.name);
```

I understand that the rxjs observable is asynchronous so value will be `undefined` at the last line `console.log(...)`. Is there any way that i can assign to value from observable to a global variable? Something like wait for the `getAuthUser()` async method to finish then assign it to the global variable.

Comment: It works. You just use `console.log` in the wrong place. PS Actually currentUser isn't global in your example it's just a property of your object.

Comment: Are you aware of the async pipe? In your template, you can just subscribe to the observable, you dont necessarily need the global variable, you can just do: <span *ngIf="userService.getAuthUser() | async; let user">{{user.name}}</span>. In Angular, Observables are first class citizens.

Comment: Also no need to specify public, fields are public by default in TypeScript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the code below this will assign the value to the `user` only when data is available:

```
public currentUser: User;

this.userService.getAuthUser().subscribe(user => {
   this.currentUser = user;
   console.log(this.currentUser.name);
});
```